# How to move a pivotchart to a sheet using epplus and c#

Tags: c#, charts, pivot, epplus

Does anyone know how to **move a pivotchart to a separate worksheet** by code using EPPlus and C#?

Using Excel I can move a pivotchart by the following steps:

1. [Right click on chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zurq2.png)
2. Select "New Worksheet"
3. Press [OK]

I cannot figure out how to do the same by c# code.

Moving the pivotchart to a separate sheet, setting location to `(0,0)`  and size to `100%` does *not* stretch the chart to the size of the sheet's view.

There is a method `ExcelWorksheets.AddChart()` on the Worksheets collection of the Workbook but it throws the following exception:

`System.NotSupportedException: This property or method is not supported for a Chartsheet`

```cs
public ExcelChartsheet AddChart(string Name, eChartType chartType);
```

Any ideas oder hints anyone?

Many thanks!
Jan